# when I trying to convert my h5 files to mlmodel with coremltool I keep getting this error ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a cnn model that I use keras and tensorflow. I want to use this in my ios'app. In this I am trying to convert it with coremltool.

```
import coremltools
import keras
import tensorflow


output_labels = [0,1]
scale = 1/255.


coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("new_model.h5",
                                          input_names="image",image_input_names="image",
                                          output_names="output",
                                          class_labels= output_labels,
                                          image_scale=scale)

coreml_model.author = "x"
coreml_model.license = "y"
coreml_model.short_description = "z"
coreml_model.input_description['image'] = 'a'
coreml_model.output_description['output'] = 'bc'

coreml_model.save('model_new.mlmodel')
```

In here `coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert`. I try tensorflow.convert then ı get ImportError: Failed to import TensorFlow utilities. No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.saving'. Error. Then ı use keras instead of tensorflow at that time I get this error.  `ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform`.

Comment: Try to save your model in .hdf5 format

Comment: did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find